# Call Meteor from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, meteor

I writes simple todo app in Meteor. I added to my code *sweetAlert* and I've got some issue with deleting tasks after approval. It looks as this command could not be performed

```
Tasks.remove(this.props.task._id);
```

Why this command will not be executed? How I can remove this task, after confirmation?

Source file

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { Tasks } from '../api/tasks.js';
import sweetAlert from 'sweetalert';

// Task component - represents a single todo item
export default class Task extends Component {
  toggledChecked() {
    Tasks.update(this.props.task._id, {
      $set: { checked: !this.props.task.checked },
    });
  }

  deleteThisTask() {
    sweetAlert( {
      title: "Are you sure for delete this item?",
      text: this.props.task.text,
      type: "warning",
      showCancelButton: true,
      confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
      confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
      cancelButtonText: "No, cancel plx!",
      closeOnConfirm: false,
      closeOnCancel: true,
    }, function() {
        Tasks.remove(this.props.task._id);
        sweetAlert("Delted!", "Your imaginary file has been deleted.", "success");
    });
    // Tasks.remove(this.props.task._id);
  }
```

Comment: do your allow/deny rules allow removals? or are you still using the `insecure` package?

Comment: What's the error message in the browser console?